# IE9 not rendering background-image

Tags: internet-explorer, css, internet-explorer-9, background-image

I've find many questions regarding IE9 not rendering background-image but cannot find a solution that fit my needs.

I use a CSS3 gradient generator for my background and that works ok for all modern browsers except in IE9.

The code im using is:

```
body {
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(184,190,227) 49%, rgb(118,135,250) 80%);
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(184,190,227) 49%, rgb(118,135,250) 80%);
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(184,190,227) 49%, rgb(118,135,250) 80%);
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(184,190,227) 49%, rgb(118,135,250) 80%);
 background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(184,190,227) 49%, rgb(118,135,250) 80%);
 background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,left top,color-stop(0.49, rgb(184,190,227)),color-stop(0.8, rgb(118,135,250)));
}
```

Ive setted a jsFiddle page: http://jsfiddle.net/nUA98/

So, if anyone knows why it is not working in IE9, comment/answer will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: caniuse.com is a very useful resource: [CSS Gradients](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients)

Comment: @Stefan  Seems like complete ressource, put it in my favorites, great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that IE9 doesn't render background images, it's just that, if you want to use a gradient in IE9, you have to use SVG. Create your gradient using [ColorZilla](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/), and make sure to check the "IE9 support" option at the end. It automatically generates a data-uri SVG for you to use, without having to actually use an image file.

Answer (score 1):

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fff', endColorstr='#f2f2f2');
```

Answer (score 0):

ie9 won't support rgba format so try this
`filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f8cbd6', endColorstr='#edeeec',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */`